# find all pairs of rows within pandas dataframe with times within 60s

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> df
   X         Y
0  a  2021-02-26 06:30:00
1  b  2021-02-26 06:30:30
2  c  2021-02-26 06:30:45
3  d  2021-02-26 06:31:30
4  e  2021-02-26 06:31:50
```

I want to find all pairs of X where the Y is within 60s.

So I want:

a, b

a, c

b, c

b, d

c, d

d, e

I know I can use loop over the data and compare, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way to do this e.g. with filter and grouper

Comment: If you worry about time, python isn't that fast of a language to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from datetime import timedelta

data = StringIO(
"""
X  Y
0  a  2021-02-26 06:30:00
1  b  2021-02-26 06:30:30
2  c  2021-02-26 06:30:45
3  d  2021-02-26 06:31:30
4  e  2021-02-26 06:31:50
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='  ')

df['Y'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Y'])

# add key for cross join
df['key'] = 0

# cross join
df = df.merge(df, on='key', suffixes = ('', '_intermediate'))

df[(df['Y_intermediate'] > df['Y'])
   & (df['Y_intermediate'] - df['Y'] <= timedelta(seconds=60))][['X', 'X_intermediate']]

df
```

gives:

[image: output result]

Answer (score 0):

It's tempting to use `.merge_asof` function here:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(
"""
X  Y
0  a  2021-02-26 06:30:00
1  b  2021-02-26 06:30:30
2  c  2021-02-26 06:30:45
3  d  2021-02-26 06:31:30
4  e  2021-02-26 06:31:50
""".strip())

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='  ')
df['Y'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Y'])

pd.merge_asof(df, df, on='Y', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('60 s'), allow_exact_matches=False, direction='forward')
```

However, as you can see from the output, it will match only one item for each left entry. Since you are interested in non-unique matches, it's a more complex challenge that will require forming all potential combinations of values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer hope this helps:

1. convert 'X' column to index:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({
        'X': [ 'a','b','c','d','e'],
        'Y' : [ '2021-02-26 06:30:00','2021-02-26 06:30:30','2021-02-26 06:30:45','2021-02-26 06:31:30', '2021-02-26 06:31:50'],
       })
df["Y"]= pd.to_datetime(df["Y"])
df.index = df['X'] 
df = df.drop('X',axis=1)
```

2. Create all possible combinations and store them in another data frame:

```
comb_list = list(combinations(df.index.to_list(),2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(comb_list)
df2.index = comb_list
df2['Result'] = df2.apply(lambda row : df.loc[row[1]]['Y'] - df.loc[row[0]]['Y'] , axis = 1 )
output = df2[df2['Result'] <= pd.Timedelta(60,'S')].index.to_list()
print(output)
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e')]
```